# Convert ethereum balance getting in biginteger to ether

Tags: ether, web3j

```
public BigInteger getBalance(String address) 
{
    /*Web3j web3j  */

   createEthreumConnection();
   EthGetBalance ethGetBalance = null;
   try {
      ethGetBalance = web.ethGetBalance(address, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST).sendAsync().get();
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {               
      logger.error("Interrupted Exception "+e);
   } catch (ExecutionException e) {         
      logger.error("ExecutionException Exception "+e);
   }
   return ethGetBalance.getBalance();
}
```

I am using the above code for getting the ethereum balance but the balance fetched in given format 4555500000 , I want to be shown as Ethereum balance.For example Bitcoin j provides  MonetaryFormat.BTC.noCode().format(addressBalance)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Luiz Soares Thank you for giving me the clue of the value being in WEI but solution provided didn't worked me.After some digging the documentation again got the solution

Convert.fromWei(ethGetBalance.getBalance().toString(), Unit.ETHER);

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the value in wei

> web3.eth.getBalance returns a BigNumber instance of the current balance for the given address in WEI. https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#returns-33

To converte to Ether:
`var value = web3.fromWei('21000000000000', 'ether');`

> https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3fromwei